# disable escaping single quotes within string from bash read builtin command

Tags: bash, shell, single-quotes

i want to process files from a text file containing single quoted file names, like

```
'new'$'\n''line'
'tab'$'\t''ulator'
```

copy & paste for manually processing this files works fine:

```
test -f 'tab'$'\t''ulator'
```

now, reading from file with bash read builtin command

```
while IFS="" read -r myfile; do
  line=$myfile
  ...
done < text.txt
```

give strings containing escaped single quotes, like

```
'\''new'\''$'\''\n'\'''\''line'\'''
'\''tab'\''$'\''\t'\'''\''ulator'\'''
```

however, processing this file names in bash script does not work.

```
test -f "$myfile"
test -f ${myfile}
```

how to disable /undo escaping single quotes and process raw file name within bash?

Comment: Reading the file via the `read` command does not alter the data within.  If you are genuinely producing a version with escaped quotes then that's a function of how you are outputting the data.  I suspect you have a misconception somewhere, but any way around I don't think we'll be able to answer your question unless you provide a [mcve].

Comment: More precisely, *`read -r`* with a single variable name does not alter the data.  Without the `-r`, `read` recognizes the `\ ` as an escape character.  With multiple names, `read` performs word splitting.  But in the case presented, it does neither of those things.

Comment: You could `eval` those strings but, generally, `eval` should be considered a last choice.  Do you have any control over the text files that you are trying to read from?  There are many other formats that would be superior.

Comment: for reproducing, create some files containing linefeed or tabulator in file name, then stat -c %N * > text.txt. bash -x script.sh shows the escaped strings. the text file is just a index of files created by myself.

Comment: @alecxs How about replacing that with `printf '%s\0' *`?  This produces NUL-separated strings which can be safely and reliably interpreted.

Comment: @John1024 i use stat -c "%04a"$'\011'"%u:%g"$'\011'"%F"$'\011'"%N" this is a human readable table and easy to modify, each file is a new line - it is safe enough in my case, i guess. but thanks anyway, i agree in most cases it is useful to NUL-separate

Comment: @alecxs OK.  If you like, you can simplify the quoting in that `stat` command this way: `stat -c $'%04a\t%u:%g\t%F\t%N' *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `eval`

Many people quite reasonably regard [`eval` as a mis-spelling of evil](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).
So, I would regard this solution as last-choice to be used only if all else fails.

Let's take this sample file:

```
$ cat badformat
'new'$'\n''line'
'tab'$'\t''ulator'
```

We can read and interpret these file names as in the following example:

```
while read -r f; do
    eval "f=$f"; [ -f "$f" ] || echo "file not found"
done <badformat
```

#### Using NUL-separated lists of file names

The only character that cannot be in a Unix file name is NUL (hex 00).  Consequently, many Unix tools are designed to be able to handle NUL-separated lists.

Thus, when creating the file, replace:

```
stat -c %N * >badformat
```

with:

```
printf '%s\0' * >safeformat
```

This latter file can be read into shell scripts via a while-read loop.  For example:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
    [ -f "$f" ] || echo "file not found"
done <safeformat
```

In addition to shell while-read loops, note that `grep`, `find`, `sort`, `xargs`, as well as GNU `sed` and GNU `awk`, all have the native ability to handle NUL-separated lists.  Thus, the NUL-separated list approach is both safe and well-supported.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution with string manipulating

```
${filename//$'\047'\\$'\047'$'\047'/$'\047'}
```

as you mentioned above, using eval is very dangerous for filenames like 'rm -rf'. regarding stat -c %N (which only escapes single quotes, linefeeds and tabs) there is another solution

```
while IFS="" read -r myfile; do

  filename="$myfile"

  filename="${filename#?}"
  filename="${filename%?}"
  filename="${filename//"'$'\t''"/$'\011'}"
  filename="${filename//"'$'\n''"/$'\012'}"
  filename="${filename//$'\047'\\$'\047'$'\047'/$'\047'}"

  test -f "$filename" && echo "$myfile exists"

done < text.txt
```